# Discord.JS voiceStateUpdate newState chanelID is null

Tags: discord.js

In my discord bot a sound should be played when a user joins to the server. 
Playback and everything else is working, but the **newState** object created when voiceStateUpdate is fired **does not contain a channelID**. 
I get a chanelID when the user changes between chanels but not when joining from outside.

*Im using Discord.js v13.0*

```
module.exports = (oldState, newState) => {
    console.log(newState.channelID);
};
```

Event Handeling:

```
const evt = require(`./events/${file}`);
let evtName = file.split(".")[0];
console.log(`Loaded event '${evtName}'`);
client.on(evtName, evt.bind(null, client));
```

Console Output Outside Join:

```
channelID: null
```

Console Output Channel-Change:

```
channelID: '6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing `client` as a parameter in your module export, so I'm guessing that your `oldState` has the client values and `newState` has the actual oldState values. Try adding `client` to the start of your `module.exports`.

```js
module.exports = (client, oldState, newState) => {
    // Stuff
}
```

Not sure if this is correct though as you did not provide any code of your event handling.

Comment: Not sure why you would need to pass an _unused_ parameter to that function. Especially, if it's the [`voiceStateuUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) event handler that takes two parameters. The first one is the old voice state, and the second one is the new voice state.

Comment: This worked! Semms like the documentation is wrong. To this function 3 parameters get passed. The third one ist the newState

Comment: The documentation is correct, but we've got no idea what you do with this exported module.

Comment: That is exactly why I **assumed** that he might need to add `client` there...

Answer (score 0):

You need to type `channelID` this way : `channelId`

```
module.exports = (oldState, newState) => {
    console.log(newState.channelId);
};
```

Check : https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channelId

Comment: Thanks for the info, but i also checked the newState object and all its keys and it doesent contain an chanelId

Comment: I just tested the code on my own with discord.js@13.3.1, it works fine. Perhaps, your event handler is the cause of your problem. Could you provide your code handling the `voiceStateUpdate` event. You could also try to use the `newState.channel` property.

Comment: I added the event handeling in the original question. I tested the solution provided by NotTrixxie and it worked. The first argument is indeed  client.